# Sinon stubs not "called" after first test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, socket.io, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to write some basic tests for my socket.io server, but I am having trouble getting my tests to run together. For some reason, my stubs are called in the first test, but not in the following tests that check different stubs/spies. If you change the order the tests are defined in the test file, whichever one is first passes.

Here is my simplified module being tested (server.js):

```
var exports = module.exports = {},
    io = require('socket.io')(8080);

function startServer() {
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.emit('loading');
    });
};

exports.startServer = startServer;
```

and here is my test file:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect,
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    mockery = require('mockery');

describe('bidding-war-server', function () {
    var biddingWarServer,
        stubbedIo;

    before(function () {
        mockery.enable();
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        stubbedIo = {
            on: function() { }
        };
        var mockSocketIo = function (port) {
            return stubbedIo;
        };

        mockery.deregisterAll();
        mockery.registerAllowable('./server');
        mockery.registerMock('socket.io', mockSocketIo);
        biddingWarServer = require('./server');
    });

    after(function () {
        mockery.deregisterAll();
        mockery.disable();
    });

    it('should call socket.emit loading', function () {
        var stubbedSocket = {
            emit: sinon.spy(),
        };
        stubbedIo.on = sinon.stub().callsArgWith(1, stubbedSocket);

        biddingWarServer.startServer();

        expect(stubbedSocket.emit.called).to.be.true;
    });

    it('should setup io.on connection', function () {
        stubbedIo.on = sinon.spy();

        biddingWarServer.startServer();

        expect(stubbedIo.on.called).to.be.true;
    });
});
```

Does anyone see what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue origins from module caching - your `server.js` is loaded only once.

To resolve this, I eventually came to executing `mockery.enable` and `mockery.disable` in `beforeEach` and `afterEach` blocks respectively, also forcing `mockery` to use clean cache.

Please have a look at updated test file:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect,
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    mockery = require('mockery');

describe('bidding-war-server', function () {
    var biddingWarServer,
        stubbedIo;

    beforeEach(function () {
        stubbedIo = {
            on: function() { }
        };
        var mockSocketIo = function (port) {
            return stubbedIo;
        };

        mockery.registerAllowable('./server');
        mockery.registerMock('socket.io', mockSocketIo);
        mockery.enable({useCleanCache: true});

        biddingWarServer = require('./server');
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        mockery.deregisterAll();
        mockery.disable();
    });

    it('should call socket.emit loading', function () {
        var stubbedSocket = {
            emit: sinon.spy(),
        };
        stubbedIo.on = sinon.stub().callsArgWith(1, stubbedSocket);

        biddingWarServer.startServer();

        expect(stubbedSocket.emit.called).to.be.true;
    });

    it('should setup io.on connection', function () {
        stubbedIo.on = sinon.spy();

        biddingWarServer.startServer();

        expect(stubbedIo.on.called).to.be.true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I initially thought my stubs were setup incorrectly. It looks like adding `mockery.resetCache()` in the beforeEach with `mockery.enable({useCleanCache: true})` in the before and `mockery.disable()` in the after works as well. I would prefer your answer though. Thanks!